# How do I change the appearance of the selected button in a row of Material Design buttons?

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have a HTML table and in several rows I have a Material Design button in each cell, dynamically generated using AngularJS.

[image]

```
<table class="plans">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Plans</td>
            <td ng-click="pbmainController.selectPlan(plan.planName)"
                ng-repeat="plan in pbmainController.planList">
                    <md-button class="md-raised">{{plan.planName}}</md-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Only one of button can be selected at a time (i.e. like a radio button).

How do I change the color of the selected button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by putting the `ng-class` on the button, using the ternary operator

```
<table class="plans">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Plans</td>
            <td ng-click="pbmainController.selectPlan(plan.planName)"
                ng-repeat="plan in pbmainController.planList">
                    <md-button ng-class="plan.planName == selectedPlanName ? 'md-raised md-primary' : 'md-raised'">{{plan.planName}}</md-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what if i want to remove a hover effect once the button is clicked,md-button have the hover transparent gray color effect. looked similar to this question of mine.                                                                                          ` <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.widget.type = 'chart'; $ctrl.validateForm()" layout='column'  ng-class="{selIcon : $ctrl.widget.type == 'chart'}">
                    <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-src="trending-up"></md-icon>
                    <label>{{'LABELS.CHART' | translate}}</label>
                </md-button>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933188/anguar-material-md-button-hover-color-change?noredirect=1#comment76886250_44933188

Answer (score 3):

A `ng-class` attribute will do the trick.

In your function selectPlan you probably save the name somewhere. Assuming this var is named `selectedPlan`, you can do something like this :

```
<table class="plans">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Work Plans</td>
            <td ng-click="pbmainController.selectPlan(plan.planName)"                   
                ng-repeat="plan in pbmainController.planList">
                    <md-button  ng-class="{'active' : plan.planName == selectedPlan}" class="md-raised">{{plan.planName}}</md-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`ng-class` will be apply your class (here `active`) only when the condition is true. So only when your plan is the selected one.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I even tried `ng-class="{'md-warn' : 1==1}"`, which I thought would unconditionally turn all the buttons red.

Comment: The `ng-class` has to be on the `md-button` and not on the `<td>`