# Angular material md-button hover color change

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, saas

```
 <div class="non-active" layout layout-align='space-around center'> 
            <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.widget.type = 'chart'; $ctrl.validateForm()" layout='column'  ng-class="{selIcon : $ctrl.widget.type == 'chart'}">
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-src="trending-up"></md-icon>
                <label>{{'LABELS.CHART' | translate}}</label>
            </md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.widget.type = 'card';$ctrl.validateForm()" layout='column' ng-class="{selIcon : $ctrl.widget.type == 'card'}">
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-src="info-white"></md-icon>
                {{'LABELS.CARD' | translate}}
            </md-button>

            <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.widget.type = 'currentValue'; $ctrl.validateForm()" layout='column' ng-class="{selIcon : $ctrl.widget.type == 'currentValue'}">
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-src="filter2"></md-icon>
                {{'LABELS.CURRENTVAL' | translate}}
            </md-button>
        </div>

   ///csss

       .selIcon {
           background: #91a865;
        }
      .non-active{

      .md-active-button:hover{
       background-color: #91a865;
       }

      }
```

[image]
[image]

as you can see, my button when clicked is set to green not by md-raised but by simple css (.selIcon {
  background: #91a865;
}) . The only problem is I want to remove the hover effect to gray color. once the button is clicked and turned green when I hover it's going to gray. How do I disable this feature? also, can I wrap it inside a div so the hover disable only affect this particular button

Comment: what is the expected behaviour on hover?

Comment: stay green. when the button is clicked it turns green, or say no hover effect once initially clicked and turn green. green is selected to show the button is selected

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a code editor (plunker, codepen, or jsfiddle) and share the link here?

Comment: use `md-no-ink` with ng-class.

Comment: how would i add that? sorry not very good at the material . i tried `ng-class="{selIcon : $ctrl.widget.type == 'chart' md-no-ink}"` but it's disabling the initial green on click. just want the gray on hover removed, I believe all md -button have this transparent grey on hover

Comment: @Nehal here u go, as you can see all the button have the hover effect, kinda want to remove that hover effect only. green color on green should stay https://codepen.io/nanarth/pen/qEEpZV

Comment: Check the raised buttons (regular and primary) here. 
https://codepen.io/nehal90/pen/bRjzgE

Comment: you will have to override the `:hover` of the element based on the class applied, like `md-button.active:hover` and `md-button.in-active:hover`

Comment: @redflar3 i updated the code in the question. still no change tho  wrapped inside a div class so the change only affects the button inside that class . is there a way to do it with ng-class and itinerary operator?

Comment: @AnuRajan, do you have any feedback on the codepen I provided?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to target the class of the `md-button` element which is `.md-button` and change the `background-color` using css. `md-button` element of angular material by default has the grey background color.
[Here is a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fNQA3vOl2R8vCwkcN5zQ?p=preview)