# Angular Material - set button active

Tags: angular-material

I use this navigation in my Angular 5/Angular Materials application:

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<mat-toolbar color="warn">  
 <mat-toolbar-row>
  <span class="nav-icon">
    My Icon
  </span>

  <span class="nav-spacer"></span>

  <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</button> 
  <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
 </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<!-- Router Outlet -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Actually I could not find how to set the active menu button active. Is there a way of doing this, e.g. with Route?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the appearance of the selected button in a row of Material Design buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269802/how-do-i-change-the-appearance-of-the-selected-button-in-a-row-of-material-desig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps someone the active class was not working for me I'm using Angular version 12.0.5

I replaced:

```html
<button mat-raised-button routerLink="/overview/anxietydepressionchart/{{id}}" routerLinkActive="activebutton">Anxiety Depression Graph</button>
```

With:

```html
<a mat-raised-button routerLink="/overview/anxietydepressionchart/{{id}}" routerLinkActive="activebutton" >Anxiety Depression Graph</a>
```

CSS:

```css
.activebutton 
{
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: white;
}
```

This solved my active button issues.

Answer (score 30):

In Angular 6 you can add the `routerLinkActive` attribute to buttons. When the corresponding route is the current one, the content of this attribute will be added to the element's css classes.

For example:

```html
<button mat-button [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="mat-accent">
    Home
</button>
```

When this button is clicked **and the corresponding route becomes the active one**, it will get the additional `mat-accent` CSS class.

Reference: [Angular.io docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links), [Angular API docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)

Comment: In case the mat-button displays a component (not changing the route), how can you make your mat-button active ? Tried with ngClass without success...

Comment: ok got it for the ngClass on the button. Nevertheless, there is no other smart ways to do that ?