# How I can change material button type with routerLinkActive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

Is it poosible to change material button type and color property with routerLinkActive property?
I need change code from this:

```
<button mat-stroked-button
    color="basic"
    [routerLink]="['/about']">About
</button>
```

to this:

```
<button mat-flat-button 
    color="accent"
    [routerLink]="['/about']">About
</button>
```

Comment: You could use `routerLinkActive` attribute to set active style as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50250927/5171009

Comment: @Prabh this question is not about accent color but about button type

Answer (score 0):

You can use routerLinkActive="active" to set the color

```
<button mat-flat-button routerLinkActive="accent"    [routerLink]="['/about']">About
</button>
```

in your css

```
    .accent{
background-color : whatever you like
}
```

Comment: But how I can change mat-stroked-button type to mat-flat-button ?

Comment: add some styles in .accent class